# Queue Up Mail if Mail Server is Down?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have a database that uses @MailSend and .Send() methods on various forms for notifications. We had an issue where our mail server went down so email was unable to be sent out.

I'm under the assumption that running @MailSend and .Send() on forms will be processed locally by the person running the action which will not queue the mail if the mail server set on the client is not responding.

If my assumption is correct, is there a way to fix the issue of mail not queuing? One thought is having mail processed by an agent running on the server, but I'm not sure if this would be the best way. Is this the only way to workaround this issue?

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since the server is down, how having an agent process mail on the server would help. Is the NSF file not on the mail server? Or does the user have a local replica of the NSF file?

Comment: The mail server and the database are on different servers. Sorry, I should have made that clear.

Comment: Having an agent on the app server submit the mail message is probably a good idea, but if you do it the naive way the From header will have the server name. There are ways to avoid that, either by setting the Principal field so that the message is sent "On Behalf Of" the user, or by writing the message directly to the server's mail.box. Of course, none of this will work if the admins have disabled the router task on the app server.

Comment: If "Mail file location" is set to Local (see the Location document in your Notes client), then outgoing mail is deposited in a local mail.box database and transferred to the server later.  If the server is down, mail will be held locally until the server is back up.  Of course, this configuration requires a local replica of the mail file.  Could your application require such a configuration, or is that too onerous?

Comment: I was going to mention switching to Local, but that puts the onus on the user to transfer the messages and switch the Location back to its original setting later.

Comment: Agreed.  The application probably cannot require the user switch to Local.  I mentioned it because it's a pattern the application might be able to follow:  Simulate what NotesDocument.Send() does when mail is Local, hold outbound mail in a queue on the app server, and transfer it to the user's home server mail.box when it's available.  Probably too much work if other solutions are acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. We are in the process of setting up local replicas for all users as we are moving our email to the cloud. So when the mail server (or cloud) goes down, outgoing mail will be held in the local mail.box database. I think this solves my issue. Will email automatically be sent from the local mail.box once the server is available or will the user have to manually send?

Comment: The Mail tab of the location document has a field called "Transfer outgoing mail ...".  Set that field to 1 and mail will automatically transfer whenever there is a message in mail.box.  (Btw, "Transfer outgoing mail ..." only displays when the mail file location is Local.)